# Expected a <System.ArgumentNullException> but found a <System.NullReferenceException>"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I create a test case for null argument check but got this error : Expected a <System.ArgumentNullException> to be thrown, but found a <System.NullReferenceException>: System.NullReferenceException with message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
[Fact]
public void GivenNull_WhenMapIsCalled_ThenArgumentNullExceptionIsThrown()
{
    //Given

    Request request = null;

    //When
    Action action = () => new ConsumerServiceWrapper().IndividualsSearch(request);

    //Then
    action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();

}
```

Individual Search

```
public List<Response> IndividualsSearch(Request request)
{
   var response = new List<Response>();
   //some code
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Please, share your implemetation of IndividualsSearch() method

Comment: Please, check now.

Comment: @UC57 where's the code that throws? What's behind `//some code`? What you posted doesn't throw anything, it returns an empty list. At the very least post the full exception, not just the message. The full extension text shows where the exception was thrown, any inner exceptions and the stack trace with the calls that caused the exception.

Comment: "I create a test case for null argument check but..." given that you **don't have** a null argument check, it's not surprising that it fails. Good test.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos behind some code is calling of soap service which add the response.

Comment: @nvoigt so please tell me how to do it?

Comment: uh... `if(request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));` ?